# My java project is working on Windows but some buttons dont work on MacOS

Tags: java, windows, macos, jar, compilation

I compiled my project (a quiz application) to a jar file and it is working (it tested it on a few windows machines) however if I run it on macOS (i dont own any mac so I asked my friend if he could try it) some buttons are not working (if you click on them nothing happens). 
 
Edit: The program consits of a login panel where you enter your username (one button to go to the splash panel, this button is working). On the splash Panel there are two buttons one that goes to the questions (is not working on Mac) and one that opens a new Frame with the Scoreboard (also not working on Mac)

Comment: What do the broken buttons do? Not sure we can help without seeing some code.

Comment: No code, can't help